# php click limit

Tags: php, click, limit

I have this simple click limit for my site using sessions, I would just like to know if this is ok, or an acceptable way of checking for rapid page refreshes.

This code is at the top of each page, before it requests data from the db.

```
session_start(); 
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

if ($_SESSION['click'] > date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("$now - 1 second"))) { 
    exit("You're clicking too fast") ; 
    }

$_SESSION['click'] = $now;
```

Comment: not sure what the `end` is for....

Comment: Didn't you open another topic on this matter already?

Comment: You could have put this into your original question, rather than starting a whole new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971567/php-click-limit

Comment: By using the `date` function, you're comparing dates by comparing string representations. `time` returns an integer (number of seconds since the Unix Epoch), making it better for direct comparison. If you want to be more precise (since you're only talking about a 1 sec difference), you can use `microtime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this does the same but with less functions,

```
session_start();

$now = time();

if ($_SESSION['click'] > ($now-1)) { 
    exit("You're clicking too fast") ; 
}

$_SESSION['click'] = $now;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is an acceptable way of catching rapid page refreshes from NORMAL PERSONS. Bots will throw the session cookie away and leave your check useless.

Checking the IP is not an alternative since your users could use the site from a network and/or public IP which is shared between many computers. Examples: universities, schools, workplace (yeah, right), AOL (AOL uses proxies!)

Though your code could be refined:

```
session_start(); 
$now = time();

if ($_SESSION['click'] > ($now - 1)) { 
    exit("You're clicking too fast") ; end(); 
    }

$_SESSION['click'] = $now;
```

Comment: If its a game he's creating (he has a double topic) throwing away the session cookie will log the bot out, thus leaving its move or action useless.